# What is the best way to group timestamps into intervals of given length in Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, algorithm, timestamp

I have a table for metrics in Oracle DB where one of the columns is the timestamp. I need to read the metrics from the DB and group them into given intervals of any length( 2 Month or 3 Hour or 1 Days or  2 years etc) between a starting timestamp and ending timestamp. The timestamp will be of format

`2020-05-24T18:51:10.018-07:00`

I know I can read all the entries from the table and sort them and group them into intervals by converting them all into seconds, but is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Converting them all into seconds is how I would tackle it.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. Search. Search hard if you need to.

Comment: Would a 2 months interval start at the first timestamp, or at the beginning of the month, or at the beginning of an odd month (January, March, May, July, September, November)? How about 2 years?

Comment: @OleV.V. It'd start at the beginning of the "starting timestamp".

Answer (score 0):

You may use `match_recognize` for this.

> ```
> with t(ts) as (
>   select
>     current_timestamp
>     + interval '3' minute
>     * dbms_random.value(0, level)
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 20
> )
> select *
> from t
> match_recognize(
>   order by ts asc
>   measures
>     match_number() as grp
>   all rows per match
>   pattern(a w5min*)
>   define
>     /*Rows within 5 minutes after the first row in bucket*/
>     w5min as ts - first(ts) < interval '5' minute
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> TS                  | GRP
> :------------------ | --:
> 2021-11-03 06:20:40 |   1
> 2021-11-03 06:20:56 |   1
> 2021-11-03 06:23:27 |   1
> 2021-11-03 06:23:49 |   1
> 2021-11-03 06:25:23 |   1
> 2021-11-03 06:25:36 |   1
> 2021-11-03 06:32:14 |   2
> 2021-11-03 06:34:38 |   2
> 2021-11-03 06:36:29 |   2
> 2021-11-03 06:36:59 |   2
> 2021-11-03 06:39:29 |   3
> 2021-11-03 06:40:17 |   3
> 2021-11-03 06:41:07 |   3
> 2021-11-03 06:47:14 |   4
> 2021-11-03 06:48:31 |   4
> 2021-11-03 06:52:29 |   5
> 2021-11-03 06:59:22 |   6
> 2021-11-03 07:02:05 |   6
> 2021-11-03 07:04:54 |   7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7e10e956422cf3c2bf47b4ff5ff2a765)*

Answer (score 0):

Whether it’s the best way, who can tell? If you want a Java solution, I suggest this one.

```
    OffsetDateTime[] timestamps = {
            OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-05-24T18:51:10.018-07:00"),
            OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-03-07T23:45:02.399-08:00"),
            OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-05-24T20:01:11.442-07:00"),
            OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-03-08T01:03:05.079-08:00"),
            OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-05-24T19:32:34.461-07:00"),
    };
    TemporalAmount intervalLength = Duration.ofHours(2);
    
    List<OffsetDateTime> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(timestamps));
    list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    
    List<List<OffsetDateTime>> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    if (! list.isEmpty()) {
        List<OffsetDateTime> currentGroup = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<OffsetDateTime> itr = list.iterator();
        OffsetDateTime first = itr.next();
        currentGroup.add(first);
        OffsetDateTime groupEnd = first.plus(intervalLength);
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            OffsetDateTime current = itr.next();
            if (current.isBefore(groupEnd)) {
                currentGroup.add(current);
            } else { // new group
                groups.add(currentGroup);
                currentGroup = new ArrayList<>();
                groupEnd = current.plus(intervalLength);
                currentGroup.add(current);
            }
        }
        // remember to add last group
        groups.add(currentGroup);
    }
    
    groups.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

> ```
> [2020-03-07T23:45:02.399-08:00, 2020-03-08T01:03:05.079-08:00]
> [2020-05-24T18:51:10.018-07:00, 2020-05-24T19:32:34.461-07:00, 2020-05-24T20:01:11.442-07:00]
> ```

The advantage of declaring `intervalLength` a `TemporalAmount` is you are free to assign either a time-based `Duration` to it (as above) or a date-based `Period`.

```
    TemporalAmount intervalLength = Period.ofMonths(3);
```

In this case the result is just one group:

> [2020-03-07T23:45:02.399-08:00, 2020-03-08T01:03:05.079-08:00,
> 2020-05-24T18:51:10.018-07:00, 2020-05-24T19:32:34.461-07:00,
> 2020-05-24T20:01:11.442-07:00]

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.